# How to send xml to XML-RPC web service

Tags: .net, xml, asp.net-mvc, xml-rpc, xml-rpc.net

.NET MVC 4.5 in C#
xml-rpc.net library from Charles Cook

Trying to hit a 3rd party vendor with xml-rpc.  I need to send them some xml formatted like the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?> 
<QuoteRequest> 
    <User_ID>XXXXXXXX</User_ID> 
    <State>AL</State> 
    <Zip_Code>35201</Zip_Code> 
    <Applicant_Gender>Male</Applicant_Gender> 
    <Applicant_Age>30</Applicant_Age> 
    <Plan_ID>10</Plan_ID>
</QuoteRequest>
```

My efforts thus far:

```
var quoteRequest = new XmlRpcStruct();
var quoteRequestSpecs = new XmlRpcStruct();
quoteRequestSpecs.Add("Plan_ID", "10");
//add in other bits of xml here...user id, state, zip code, etc

quoteRequest.Add("QuoteRequest", quoteRequestSpecs);

var proxy = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<IQuoteRequest>();
proxy.Url = "http://myfakeurl.com"
var response = proxy.QuoteRequest(quoteRequest);
```

and the IQuoteRequest looks like the following:

```
public interface IQuoteRequest : IXmlRpcProxy
{
    [XmlRpcMethod("QuoteRequest")]
    string QuoteRequest(XmlRpcStruct request);
}
```

I hit the service fine, but all I get back is the following:

```
"&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;iso-8859-1&quot;?&gt;&lt;QuoteResult&gt;&lt;Error&gt;&lt;Message&gt;Incorrect Plan ID.#&lt;/Message&gt;&lt;/Error&gt;&lt;/QuoteResult&gt;"
```

Important part: "Incorrect Plan ID".

Yes, I know I'm using the correct plan ID.

I get the same message if I attach no information at all and just send across an empty XmlRpcStruct, so I don't think my data is getting sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just needing to pass a string, not actual xml.

```
var quoteRequest = "<QuoteRequest><User_ID>XXXXXXXXX</User_ID><State>TX</State><Zip_Code>75251</Zip_Code><Applicant_Gender>Male</Applicant_Gender><Plan_ID>10</Plan_ID></QuoteRequest>";

var proxy = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<IQuoteRequest>();
proxy.Url = "http://myfakeurl.com"
var response = proxy.QuoteRequest(quoteRequest);
```

and IQuoteRequest looks like:

```
public interface IQuoteRequest : IXmlRpcProxy
{
    [XmlRpcMethod("QuoteRequest")]
    string QuoteRequest(string request);
}
```